# Calculate salary based on weekday

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am calculating employee salary for the given dates, in week days his salary will be $100 and in week ends salary will be $150  this rate will be different for other employees, I am maintaining this information employee table as weekdayrate and weekendrate for each employee.

I want the out put as :

```
EmpId Name  Day       Date          Salary
11    abc   Thursday  05/07/2020    $100
11    abc   Friday    05/08/2020    $100
11    abc   Saturday  05/09/2020    $150
11    abc   Sunday    05/10/2020    $150
```

Can someone help me to do this in Sql Server?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Just create a calendar table, makes this so easy. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't care about bank holidays you'd just have something like this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/403353/3/0

You need at least a table of employees, a table of rates, and a table which says which employees have worked which days.

Schema creation & sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE DayRates(RateId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Rate DECIMAL(12,2))

CREATE TABLE Employees(
  EmpId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [Name] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
  WeekdayRateId INT NOT NULL,    
  WeekendRateId INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_Employee_WeekdayRateId FOREIGN KEY(WeekdayRateId) REFERENCES DayRates(RateId),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Employee_WeekendRateId FOREIGN KEY(WeekendRateId) REFERENCES DayRates(RateId),
  )

CREATE TABLE EmployeeWorkDays(
  EmployeeWorkDayId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  EmpId INT NOT NULL,
  [Date] DATETIME NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeeWorkdDays_EmpId FOREIGN KEY(EmpId)  REFERENCES Employees(EmpId),
  )

INSERT DayRates VALUES (1,100),(2,150)
INSERT Employees VALUES (1, 'Joe', 1, 2)
INSERT EmployeeWorkDays (EmpId, [Date]) VALUES (1, '05/07/2020'),(1, '05/08/2020'),(1, '05/09/2020'),(1, '05/10/2020')
```

Query:

```
SELECT
  e.EmpId, e.[Name], ewd.[Date], DATENAME(WEEKDAY, ewd.[Date]) As Day
  ,CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ewd.[Date]) WHEN 1 THEN r2.Rate 
                                      WHEN 7 THEN r2.Rate 
                                      ELSE  r1.Rate END As [Salary]
FROM Employees e
JOIN EmployeeWorkDays ewd ON e.EmpId = ewd.EmpId
JOIN DayRates As r1 ON e.WeekdayRateId = r1.RateId
JOIN DayRates As r2 ON e.WeekendRateId = r2.RateId
```

That will yield the desired results:

```
EmpId   Name    Date                    Day         Salary
1       Joe     2020-05-07T00:00:00Z    Thursday    100
1       Joe     2020-05-08T00:00:00Z    Friday      100
1       Joe     2020-05-09T00:00:00Z    Saturday    150
1       Joe     2020-05-10T00:00:00Z    Sunday      150
```

If you need to account for bank holidays your database will need to include a calendar. See the comment by @arron-bertrand for details on how you might do that